# IIS URL rewrite with optional parameters for page no

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I need a help writing rewrite rule for the following url pattern

```
www.mydomain.com/list-of-(buyers|suppers|all)-in-(location-name)/page/10.html
```

1. The first parameter will be 'buyers' or 'suppliers' or 'all'
2. The second parameter can be ANY location name
3. '/page/number' part is optional
4. url will always end with '.html'

**UPDATE:**

I have managed to write a rewrite rule which successfully matches the following url:

`mysite.com/list-of-buyers-in-goa/page/5.html`.

The same rule is not working for the below url

`mysite.com/list-of-buyers-in-goa.html`

i.e. when I remove the `page/no` part from the url, it doesn't work. I don't need page/no parameter for the first page.

Since all the other pages on website are `.html` pages, just to maintain the uniformity, I want the url to always end with `.html`

Here is my rewrite rule

```
    <rule name="Rewrite rule for listing members">
      <match url="^list-of-([a-z-A-z]+)-in-([a-zA-z-]+)?(\/page\/)?([\d+])?\.html$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="members.aspx?type={R:1}&amp;location={R:2}&amp;page={R:4}" />
    </rule>
```

--

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
.*.com\/list-of-(buyers|suppers|all)-in-.*html$
```

I tested it with *"mysite.com/list-of-buyers-in-goa.html"* and *mysite.com/list-of-buyers-in-goa/page/1234.html*, it matched.

Comment: this rule does not match the optional 'page/no' part.

Comment: Would you provide sample URL ?

Comment: here are the sample urls

* `mysite.com/list-of-buyers-in-goa.html`
* `mysite.com/list-of-buyers-in-goa/page/1234.html`

the above urls have three parameters

1. **buyers**
2. **goa**
3. **1234**

I need a rule that would match both the above urls

Comment: Hi @Rainman, I tried your updated rule but it did not work. Besides I want to match complete url, which begins with `list-of-` and then matches mandatory parameters, matches static `-in-` string, matches the `page no` parameter if found and then ends with `.html`

Comment: I updated my answer. And be careful with ".com" extension.